# Access IIS Dev. Server from Virtual Machine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, vmware

I am running Visual Studio on my local Windows Server webdev machine. This launches an ASP.NET Development Server when I run my website.

I need to test this in various versions/browsers/tools and thus I'd like to access it from a VM, without having to deploy it each time I want to test something.

Therefore: is there a way to access my local ASP.NET server from my VM?

Can I use a reverse proxy or something for this? If so how? Why can I access the IIS7 welcome page but not the instance of my webserver on specific port?

Cheers

Edited to differentiate Cassini ASP.NET Dev. Server and IIS7.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings to make sure another machine can access your workstation's IIS?

Comment: this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: asp.net dev server != iis7 && asp.net dev server ~= iis express && iis 7 ~= iis express

Comment: asp.net's development web server and iis express are restricted to the local machine only.

Comment: @Daniel A. White
Is there no way to grant access to this from a VM then? Seems like since I'm running on the same machine and using a bridged connection this should be possible.

Comment: @LorneSchultz The great thing is that you can 'ping' your local server from your VM (as you can access the IIS7 welcome page). Is your website in some folder different that default ? may be you just need to go to "basic settings" --> "physical path" and choose your folderProject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found a way to do this using Fiddler.](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp)

Basically you just create a reverse proxy on the dev. machine like so:

if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "192.168.0.100:8888") oSession.host = "localhost:41111";

Where my ASP.NET dev server (from VS2010) is running on localhost:41111 and I access it from other machines on the local network (or VMs) using 192.168.0.100:8888 (mydevhostip:8888) in a browser.